# Nonnegative Interval Integration

Tags: isabelle

I'm looking for lemma state that in interval integration, if the function is nonnegative or equal to zero then the integration is nonnegative or equal to zero as well. I've seen this property in other integration theories but not in interval integration. 
I tried this lemma:

lemma m4: 
fixes a b M
assumes
"interval_lebesgue_integrable M a b (λx. f x)"
"⋀x. 0 ≤ f x"
"⋀t. set_integrable M (einterval a b) (λx. f x)"
"(⋀ a b. a≥0  ∧ a ≤ b )"
shows "(LINT t=a..b|M.  f x) ≥0"

but when I tried use "quickcheck" I've got this error message:
For instantiation with default_type Enum.finite_1:
Enum.finite_1 to be substituted for variable 'a does not have sort {ord,banach,second_countable_topology}
For instantiation with default_type Enum.finite_2:
Enum.finite_2 to be substituted for variable 'a does not have sort {ord,banach,second_countable_topology}
For instantiation with default_type Enum.finite_3:
Enum.finite_3 to be substituted for variable 'a does not have sort {ord,banach,second_countable_topology}

I think the problem is that {ord} didn't included in the interval integration value in the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot expect Quickcheck to work on a proposition that contains integrals. Quickcheck needs to be able to generate executable code for everything involved int he proposition, and there are no code equations for integration, and it's not really possible to write any either.

As for your lemma, proving it is merely a matter of unfolding the definition and applying the corresponding lemma for ‘regular’ Lebesgue integrals.

```
lemma m4: 
  fixes a b :: ereal and f :: "real ⇒ real"
  assumes "interval_lebesgue_integrable M a b (λx. f x)" "a ≤ b" "⋀x. x ∈ {a<..<b} ⟹ 0 ≤ f x" 
  shows   "(LINT x=a..b|M. f x) ≥ 0"
  using assms unfolding interval_lebesgue_integral_def
  by (auto intro!: integral_nonneg_AE simp: indicator_def einterval_def)
```

(There were a few miatakes in the proposition you gave; I would imagine that this is the kind of theorem that you actually want)

Comment: Yes, you are right Manuel. I thought I can but I was wrong. It working now. Thanks